# Django-TastyPie reverse indirect foreign key

Tags: django, tastypie

I have the following models in my Django app where An **Order** is related to a **Cart**, a **cartItem** is related to a **Cart** and a **product**. Now in my tastypie api when i GET an order i also want to get all the products associated with the order's cart.

```
class Order(models.Model):
     objects = OrderManager()    
     order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False,unique=True,   
                                default=get_unique_order_number)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
     cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, blank=True, null=True)  
     ...


class Cart(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     is_check_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     ...

class CartItem(models.Model):
     objects = CartItemManager()
     cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
     ...

class CartRelatedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['get'] 
    excludes = ['is_check_out', 'session', 'creation_date', 'modification_date']
    include_resource_uri = False       
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()

class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    cart = fields.ForeignKey(CartRelatedResource, 'cart',full=True)

    class Meta:
       queryset = Order.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'order'
       fields = ['cart_id','delivery_time','shipping_address_id','billing_address_id',
       'tip','phone','delivery_instructions']
       include_resource_uri = False
       allowed_methods = ['post','get']
       authentication = SessionAuthentication()
       authorization = OrderAuthorization()
```

I don't think using ToManyField will work in this case. Will it? What is the best way to achieve what i want?

Comment: Maybe in `CartRelatedResource` you could define a field like this: `orders = fields.ToManyField(OrderResource, 'cart__order_set', related_name='cart')` I'm not a tastypie guy so not sure if it's gonna work..

Comment: @mariodev this will not work because OrderResource is after CartRelatedResource

Comment: Then try using the string notation with the full path.

Comment: @mariodev i get {"error": "The model '<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x0000000003C04400>' has an empty attribute 'order_set' and doesn't allow a null value."}

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it solved. As you can tell, the `products` field is the most important part:

```
class ProductRelatedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        fields = ['id', 'name']
        include_resource_uri = False


class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    products = fields.ToManyField(ProductRelatedResource,
        attribute=lambda bundle: Product.objects.filter(cartitem__cart=bundle.obj.cart), full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'order'
        include_resource_uri = False
```